# Ruby on Rails 4.2, stack level too deep, associations and delegate()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I understand the cause of a `Stack Level Too Deep` error. I am failing to spot where/why it is occurring in my code base.

I've implemented a multi-model, multi-step wizard. The first two models (`User` and `Company`) are working, it is when I attempt to add in the third (`Address`) I get the error.

I suspect the error is related to the associations between the models, although I've failed to debug.

The code snippets below function correctly except when I add the 3 lines (marked with comments in the snippet) too the file *app/wizards/user_wizard/step1.rb*.

**Relevant Models**

*app/models/company.rb*

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Validatable::Company

  # Associations:
  has_many :addresses, inverse_of: :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: :all_blank

  has_many :employees, inverse_of: :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees, reject_if: :all_blank

  has_many :licenses, inverse_of: :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :licenses, reject_if: :all_blank

  has_many :vehicles, inverse_of: :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicles, reject_if: :all_blank

  has_one :user, inverse_of: :company
end
```

*app/models/address.rb*

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations:
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :addresses

  has_many :licenses, inverse_of: :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :licenses, reject_if: :all_blank

  has_many :initial_analyses, inverse_of: :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :initial_analyses, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SoftDeletable
  include Validatable::User

  # Constants:
  MARKER_ATTRIBUTES = %w[user_name].freeze # get marked with '(deleted)'
  DEPENDANT_CHILDREN = %w[none].freeze # child resources to be deleted

  # Associations:
  belongs_to :role, inverse_of: :users

  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, reject_if: :all_blank

  has_many :auto_quotes, inverse_of: :user
end
```

*db/schema.rb*

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170616131833) do

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.text     "site_name"
    t.string   "premises_code"
    t.string   "exempt_premises_code"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "county"
    t.string   "sic_code"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.string   "country"
    t.boolean  "sic_update"
    t.boolean  "deleted",              default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
  end

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "registration_number"
    t.string   "type_of_business"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",        default: 0,  null: false
    t.string   "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.string   "invitation_token"
    t.datetime "invitation_created_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_accepted_at"
    t.integer  "invitation_limit"
    t.integer  "invited_by_id"
    t.string   "invited_by_type"
    t.integer  "invitations_count",      default: 0
  end

  add_index "users", ["company_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_id", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["invitation_token"], name: "index_users_on_invitation_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["invitations_count"], name: "index_users_on_invitations_count"
  add_index "users", ["invited_by_id"], name: "index_users_on_invited_by_id"
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true
end
```

**Wizards**

*app/wizards/user_wizard/base.rb*

```
module UserWizard
  class Base
    include ActiveModel::Model

    STEPS = %w[step1 step2].freeze

    attr_accessor :user

    delegate(*::User.attribute_names.map {|attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :user)

    def initialize(user_attributes)
      @user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

*app/wizards/user_wizard/step1.rb*

```
module UserWizard
  class Step1 < UserWizard::Base
    include Validatable::Company

    attr_accessor :company

    # One of 3 lines triggering circular reference by adding in Address model
    attr_accessor :address

    delegate(*::Company.attribute_names.map {|attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :company)

    # One of 3 lines triggering circular reference by adding in Address model
    delegate(*::Address.attribute_names.map {|attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :address)

    def initialize(user_attributes)
      super

      @company = @user.build_company

      # One of 3 lines triggering circular reference by adding in Address model
      @address = @user.company.addresses.build
    end
  end
end
```

*app/wizards/user_wizard/step2.rb*

*ommitted as it is irrelevant. code fails before ever instantiating this class*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`address` has an `address` attribute. So the delegate method is trying to create a method `address` that will be delegated to `address`.

I'd suggest this:

```
module UserWizard
  class Step1 < UserWizard::Base
    include Validatable::Company

    attr_accessor :company

    # One of 3 lines triggering circular reference by adding in Address model
    attr_accessor :company_address

    delegate(*::Company.attribute_names.map {|attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :company)

    # One of 3 lines triggering circular reference by adding in Address model
    delegate(*::Address.attribute_names.map {|attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :company_address)

    def initialize(user_attributes)
      super

      @company = @user.build_company

      # One of 3 lines triggering circular reference by adding in Address model
      @company_address = @user.company.addresses.build
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you ReggieB for finding what I couldn't.

I love programming but, failing to spot an obvious answer is frustrating! haha. Live and learn

Comment: It's the obvious ones that are hardest to spot :)